# Add navigation input filed into JavaFX web browser

Tags: javafx, javafx-2, javafx-8

I created this very simple example of JavaFX web browser.

```
            StackPane secondaryLayout = new StackPane();

            Scene secondScene = new Scene(secondaryLayout, 200, 100);

            Stage secondStage = new Stage();
            secondStage.setTitle("Second Stage");
            secondStage.setScene(secondScene);

            WebView browser = new WebView();
            WebEngine engine = browser.getEngine();
            String url = "http://zoranpavlovic.blogspot.com/";
            engine.load(url);

            StackPane sp = new StackPane();
            sp.getChildren().add(browser);
            Scene root = new Scene(sp, 600, 600);
            secondStage.setScene(root);

            secondStage.show();
```

I would like to add input filed into the to size of the window and button "Go". Can you help me to implement this?

Answer (score 0):

You can have a HBox with a textfield and a button and on button's action you can load the webengine.

I wrote the code using notepad, so errors may crept in

StackPane secondaryLayout = new StackPane();

Scene secondScene = new Scene(secondaryLayout, 200, 100);

```
 Stage secondStage = new Stage();
 secondStage.setTitle("Second Stage");
 secondStage.setScene(secondScene);

 HBox box = new HBox();
 TextField textField = new TextField();
 Button go = new Button();
 box.getChildren.addAll(textField, go);


 WebView browser = new WebView();
 WebEngine engine = browser.getEngine();

 go.setOnAction(new Eventhandler<ActionEvent>(){
     @Override public void handle(ActionEvent e) {
         String url = textField.getText();
         engine.load(url);
        } 
 });



 BorderPane sp = new BorderPane();
 sp.setTop(box);
 sp.setCenter(browser);
 Scene root = new Scene(sp, 600, 600);
 secondStage.setScene(root);

 secondStage.show();
```